# How to compare two percentages in python?

Tags: python, string, csv, comparison

I am new to python and I am dealing with some csv files. To sort these files, I have to compare some percentages in string format, such as `"5.265%"` and `"2.1545%"`. So how do I compare the actual values of these two strings? I have tried to convert them to float but it didn't work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please do share with us your attempt to convert them to floats; it was the right approach.

Comment: Try deleting the `%` at the end.

Comment: Bear in mind that testing `>` or `<` is usually okay, but testing floats for equality can by difficult or impossible! If you need very high precision or equality-testing, it's better to represent your number with two integers (one representing the "whole" part of the number; the other representing the stuff after the decimal).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Still convert them to floats, but without the `%` sign:

```
float(value.strip(' \t\n\r%'))
```

The `.strip()` removes any extra whitespace, as well as the `%` percent sign, you don't need that to be able to compare two values:

```
>>> float('5.265%  '.strip(' \t\n\r%'))
5.265
>>> float('2.1545%'.strip(' \t\n\r%'))
2.1545
```

`float()` itself will normally strip away whitespace for you but by stripping it yourself you make sure that the `%` sign is also properly removed, making this a little more robust when handling data from files.

Comment: Thanks! Could u tell me what's the meaning of the parameter ' \t\b\r%'?

Comment: Each backslash plus letter forms an escape code, `\t` is a tab, `\n` is a newline, etc. The argument to `.strip()` is seen as a set, each character in the argument is to be removed from the start and end. So this specific `.strip()` call removes all `%`, newlines, spaces, carriage returns and tabs from the start and end of your input string and returns what remains.